# How to stop MacOS XPC service

Tags: macos, service, xpc

Opening macOS Console and looking at the System Log i ran into this error message that keeps repeating itself indefinitely:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.macpaw.CleanMyMac4.HealthMonitor[21558]): Service exited with abnormal code: 78
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.macpaw.CleanMyMac4.HealthMonitor): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.macpaw.CleanMyMac4.HealthMonitor[21559]): Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 149: Could not find a bundle of the given identifier through LaunchServices: com.macpaw.CleanMyMac4.HealthMonitor
```

I also tried to search inside

```
home/Library/LaunchAgents
```

but cannot find anything about CleanMyMacX.

A few days ago I deleted the "HealthMonitor" application because it was always running in background. I think that some service is trying to keep the application alive, but how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing it there, it's likely a launch daemon, not an agent. That means the binary is located in the `/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/` directory and its registration file is located in the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` directory.